# getting out a variable from an async function, to another Python script

Tags: python, asynchronous, telethon

I'm more a beginner in python. Tried to find answers in the internet. But some things i really don't understand. Maybe here someone can help please.
I want to read out telegram messages and send them to another script. I use telethon. Actually i can print the messages. But i can't get access to variables inside the async function.
Tried different ways... Another function wrapping the async, global variable, return... nothing worked. Maybe i used the wrong syntax... But i can't find an nearly identical example anywhere.
I want to create some kind of automation, by telegram for an art project and want to send different variables from the message to different scripts and then run these scripts. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import subprocess 

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

api_hash = str(api_hash)

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

# Create the client and connect
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=['https://t.me/test238728']))
async def my_event_handler(msg):
    x = msg.raw_text
    return x

print(x)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the way to do the return by wrapping into another async function. Now i understand 'return'. Thats not what i need because it exits the function after execution. Also it tells me: Class 'TelegramClient' does not define 'await'. I need 'client.run_until_disconnected()'. I want the function keep running and updates the "global variable" every time a new message arrives.
I think the way to go, are generators and yield function... but i don' find the correct syntax to get it working. Looking forward for any help.

```
import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
import subprocess

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

api_hash = str(api_hash)

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']


# Create the client and connect


async def get_msg_async():
    client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

    found = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=['https://t.me/test23289347']))
    async def newMessageListener(event):
        newmsg = event.message.message
        found.set_result(newmsg)

    await client.start()


    return await found

def get_msg():
    return asyncio.run(get_msg_async())


print(get_msg())
```

Comment: Tried a lot with asyncio and yield but can't solve my problem. I would be very grateful on any help.